# How to get storage access on Android (Android 13)?

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I have an issue when running my application; it should display an alert/option at the beginning to request permission to access storage, but when I run it, it doesn't appear.

my MainApp.java :

```
package com.example.thesymphony;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;



import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.Manifest;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainApp extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    TextView textView;
    String[] items;
    ArrayList<AudioModel> songsList=new ArrayList<>();

    @Override    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_app);
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recylerView);
        textView=findViewById(R.id.warning);
        if (checkPermission()==false) {
            requestPermission();
            return;
        }
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION};
        String selection=MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0";

        Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            AudioModel songData=new AudioModel(cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(2));
            if (new File(songData.getPath()).exists()){
            songsList.add(songData);}
            if (songsList.size()==0){
                textView.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new MusicListAdapter(songsList,getApplicationContext()));
            }
        }
    }

    boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainApp.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    void requestPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainApp.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(MainApp.this, "Write External Storage permission. Please allow this permission in App Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainApp.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 123);
    }
}
```

my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>    <application        android:allowBackup="true"        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"        android:label="@string/app_name"        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"        android:supportsRtl="true"        android:theme="@style/Theme.TheSymphony"        tools:targetApi="31">        <activity            android:name=".MainApp"            android:exported="true"            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_app"            android:theme="@style/Theme.TheSymphony" >            <intent-filter>                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />            </intent-filter>        </activity>        <activity            android:name=".MainActivity"            android:exported="true">        </activity>    </application></manifest>
```

I want, when I run the application for the first time, a permission request to access storage to appear.

Comment: It is unclear what kind of access you want. Read or write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your app target Android 13 (targetSdkVersion 33)?

If so, you need to use the new `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES`, `READ_MEDIA_VIDEO`, and `READ_MEDIA_AUDIO` permissions.

See also:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions

Comment: What use are READ permissions if you wanna WRITE a file?

Comment: It is not as much target version of an app but Android version of used device.

Comment: @blackapps According to the link, these new permissions are only needed when you target Android 13, not for apps targeting Android 12, but running on Android 13. Of course its better to not target older releases.

Comment: No. You can target 33. But when the app runs on 29 you dont have to request these new READ permissions. Instead you use the old one.

Comment: And now please react on my first comment.